# FFmpeg - How to choose video stream based on resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to choose the video stream based on it's quality, let's say I want to choose one video stream with certain resolution.

Manually selecting the video stream is not good enough for me because I want to process many files in bulk and they have the video streams in different order, so always going for certain position would make me end up with different resolutions.

I don't want to use filters as that would make me reencode which I don't need and would make it way slower.

I've tried using the `-map` with metadata but the only key that is different is "variant_bitrate" which has slightly different values everytime, so unless I can use some wildcard or conditionals, I guess it won't work either.

What I want to try now is to obtain the exact bitrate of the stream using `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe` and then pass it to the `ffmpeg` command so it ends in something like this:

`ffmpeg -i <URL> -map m:variant_bitrate:1760000 ...`

PD: I've been reading the FFmpeg documentation and browsing the whole internet without luck.

Edit:
I managed to make it work by first using `ffprobe` to obtain stream info in json format (easier to parse), then I search for the string `"height": 540` and extract next 50 lines (counted them manually so I'm sure I'll pick the value I need), then I search for the string `variant_bitrate` and then I use a regular expression to extract the bitrate. Once I have the bitrate I make use of the MacOS clipboard (with `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`) to pass the value to the final `ffmpeg` command through the `-map` option using a metadata selector.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_streams -of json "https://streamlink.com/master.m3u8?f=dash"
| grep -A 50 '"height": 540' 
| grep variant_bitrate
| grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)' 
| pbcopy
&& ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i "https://streamlink.com/master.m3u8?f=dash" -map "0:a:0" -map "m:variant_bitrate:$(pbpaste)" -c copy "Output.mp4"
```

(added line breaks for readability)

I know it looks kinda dirty but I didn't find any other way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for this. It was helpful getting started.

You can use jq to select the stream indexes. In this case I select the highest bitrate audio and highest resolution video up to 720p:

(This is fish shell syntax but bash is very similar I think. just add dollar signs everywhere)

```
set streams (ffprobe -v error -show_streams -of json -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0' -headers 'Referer: https://emturbovid.com/' -i "https://ss216.livepie.com/stream/A/AA/WzblahblahblahzAk/master.m3u8")

set video_index (echo $streams | jq '.streams | map(select(.codec_type == "video" and .height <= 720)) | max_by(.height) | .index')
set audio_index (echo $streams | jq '.streams | map(select(.codec_type == "audio") | {index, bitrate: (.tags.variant_bitrate|tonumber)}) | max_by(.bitrate) | .index')

ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -stats -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0' -headers 'Referer: https://emturbovid.com/' -i "https://ss216.livepie.com/stream/A/AA/WzblahblahblahzAk/master.m3u8"  -map "0:$video_index" -map "0:$audio_index" out.mp4
```